The OS keeps bootlooping on IDT loading
So I created a basic IDT for my custom OS in C++, but it keeps bootlooping. gcc doesn't have any output or error at all, so I can't find the issue is.
The IDT:
#include "idt.h"
#include "isr.h"
// Define an IDT with 256 entries
IDTEntry idt[256];
IDTPointer idt_ptr;

// Assembly function to load the IDT (declared later in assembly)
extern "C" void load_idt(uint32_t);

// Function to set an entry in the IDT
void set_idt_entry(int index, uint32_t base, uint16_t selector, uint8_t type_attr) {
    idt[index].offset_low = base & 0xFFFF;         // Lower 16 bits of the ISR address
    idt[index].selector = selector;                // Segment selector
    idt[index].zero = 0;                           // Must be zero
    idt[index].type_attr = type_attr;              // Type and attributes
    idt[index].offset_high = (base >> 16) & 0xFFFF; // Upper 16 bits of the ISR address
}

// Function to initialize the IDT
void init_idt() {
    // Set up the IDT pointer
    idt_ptr.limit = sizeof(idt) - 1;
    idt_ptr.base = (uint32_t)&idt;
    
    // Initialize entries in the IDT
    set_idt_entry(0, (uint32_t)isr0_handler, 0x08, 0x8E); // Example: ISR 0 (divide by zero)
    
    // Load the IDT using assembly
    load_idt((uint32_t)&idt_ptr);
}

The isr.cpp only contains isr0_handler which just runs while (true) {}
The kernel_entry:
global load_idt
load_idt:
    ; Load the IDT using the address passed in
    ; The address of the IDT pointer is in [esp + 4]
    mov eax, [esp + 4]  ; Get the pointer to the IDTPointer structure
    lidt [eax]          ; Load the IDT using lidt instruction
    ret
section .text
    [bits 32]
    [extern main]
    call main
    jmp $

Only I didn't init IDT then it stops bootlooping. I don't know what function caused the bootloop, but it seems like when deleting until print_register (down up) the input doesn't work.
Also if you wonder what internal means, it means extern "C".

Try to simplify the code, remove parts until it works again. Then add back one line at a time until the problem comes back. At least that will tell you when and where in your code it happens. And remember that many emulators have usually have some kind of built-in debugging facilities. IIRC QEMU even have hooks for GDB.

The void print_register and all the functions below after deleting still only have no proper input (I created an input function) unless I literally delete the entire IDT it worked again.

Bochs is a good emulator for debugging IDT issues. As a general principle in osdev, if the only thing you know about your bug is that it causes a boot loop, and you can't think of any way to investigate except to stare at your code or post to SO, then you aren't using the right debugging tools, or aren't making good use of them.
